# Howto create index.php file showing newest pages automatically

Tags: php, web

I want to create an index.php file which should automatically get updated and adds links of other recently created pages ( newest pages ). So i don't want to use MySQL or a database for that. Is there any way to do that without a database?

And btw , probably i have an pagebuilder.php file which creates new pages. It should also edit the index.php file so it shows this new page on one of its sections too.

Sorry I'm a bit noob cause I'm beginning my way. So i thought there is an insane way for that.

The main content of index.php file in the include folder ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    ...
    <section>
      <a href="<?php echo newpage1 ; ?>"></a>
    <section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The index.php file

```
<?php include("pathToTheMainContent") ?>
```

And the page builder

```
<php
function () {
  $data = "mydata" ;
  fopen("newpage_path" , "w");
  fwrite($newpage  , $page_content);
  fcolse($newpage);
  fopen("index.php" , "w")
  /* sory for wrong codeing. Here it writes the variable newpage1 = "path" 
And then again it includes the index main content. But i think that's not a good idea. Thank u guys. */

 ?>
```

EDIT: I wana create a simple page builder that ( using post ) it receives the data and then thats a variable. It won't be saved in any database. It will be a variable and then the page builder will fopen a newfile and writes the variable on it. So i think it's simple now. Everything i want is to make my index.php file get updated automatically with new links to new pages.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Do you want to list the files in a directory, sorted by when they were last written?  Something else?

Comment: No. I want to go to my page builder ( probably ) and create a page and my index.php ( home ) automatically shows a link to it. The link should be added automatically.

Comment: "Probably" doesn't really clarify the specific question being asked.  What is your "page builder"?  What specifically happens when you "create a page"?  Where/how are you storing your data?  Currently it doesn't sound like a specific question, but rather a (*very*) vague idea for a website that you haven't started yet.  Can you clarify what *specific* problem you've encountered and what question you have about that problem?

Comment: Sorry. I think you write. I have edited my question. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  If you want to have a form where a user enters values to submit to the server, have you built that?  If you want PHP code which receives the values from that form and writes them to a file, have you built that?  What you have is an idea for a website (which, to be honest, is doing things in a *more difficult* way than normal, but that's your decision), but what is your specific question?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Unclear -- Are you asking about adding new links on index.php?  Or updating existing links to point to newer pages?  Or perhaps like an upsert (IODKU)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to control the file.

You can use static index.php file in include folder made already and can control the variable of file programmatically, this is the more flexible way, I think.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly but thank you.